# add record in nlog to field with dataType = date

Tags: c#, oracle, nlog

I use **nlog** dll to write to database - **oracle with entity frameWork**  in the line :

`logger.Log(logLevel, "try");`

I get in the logs of nlog the following error:

> The literal does not match the template string

**the code is:**

```
        SetPropGDC(LogEntity);
        NLog.LogLevel logLevel = SetLogLevel(Level.Debug);
        logger.Log(logLevel, "try");
        ClearGDC();



 private void SetPropGDC(LogEntity LogEntity)
    {
        GlobalDiagnosticsContext.Set(processId, LogEntity.PROCESS_ID.ToString());
        GlobalDiagnosticsContext.Set("TIME_STAMP", DateTime.Now);
        GlobalDiagnosticsContext.Set(customerId, LogEntity.CUSTOMER_ID.ToString());

    }
<targets>
<target name="TRACEDatabase" type="DataBase"  keepConnection="false" 
         dbProvider="Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client" connectionString="${gdc:connectionString}"
         commandText="insert into TLOG_SITE_GENERAL_TRACE( PROCESS_ID,TIME_STAMP,CUSTOMER_ID)
                       values(:PROCESS_ID,:TIME_STAMP,:CUSTOMER_ID)">
  <parameter name="PROCESS_ID" layout="${gdc:PROCESS_ID}" />
  <parameter name="TIME_STAMP" layout="${gdc:TIME_STAMP}" />
  <parameter name="CUSTOMER_ID" layout="${gdc:CUSTOMER_ID}" />

</target>
```

I tryed in the Web.config to change the line:

```
      <parameter name="TIME_STAMP" layout="${gdc:TIME_STAMP}" />
```

to:

```
   <parameter name="TIME_STAMP" layout="${longDate}" />
```

and I got the same error

**Can anyone help?**

Comment: Have you tried using `dbType="SqlDbType.DateTime"` for the parameter? See also https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/Database-target

Comment: @RolfKristensen  I added dbType ="SqlDbType,DateTime" now I get month invalid

Comment: Sorry didn't see you were using Oracle. Try doing this instead `dbType="DateTime"`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

NLog DatabaseTarget parameters converts to string by default. You can change the datatype by specifying `dbType` so it matches the database-column:

```
<target name="TRACEDatabase" type="DataBase">
    <parameter name="PROCESS_ID" layout="${event-properties:PROCESS_ID}" />
    <parameter name="TIME_STAMP" layout="${date}" dbType="DateTime" />
    <parameter name="CUSTOMER_ID" layout="${event-properties:CUSTOMER_ID}" />
</target>
```

Btw. it is a bad idea to use global variables for transfering context specific details.

Instead you should make use of NLog LogEventInfo Properties:

```
var logLevel = SetLogLevel(Level.Debug);
var theEvent = new NLog.LogEventInfo(logLevel, null, "try");
theEvent.Properties["PROCESS_ID"] = LogEntity.PROCESS_ID.ToString();
theEvent.Properties["CUSTOMER_ID"] = LogEntity.CUSTOMER_ID.ToString();
log.Log(theEvent);
```

See also: https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/EventProperties-Layout-Renderer