# add record nlog date get error invalid month

Tags: c#, oracle, date, nlog

I use **nlog** dll to write to database - **oracle with entity frameWork**  in the line :

```
logger.Log(logLevel, "try");
```

I get in the logs of NLog the following error:

> Warn   DatabaseTarget: Parameter: 'TIME_STAMP' - Failed to assign DbType=OracleDbType.Date
>         Error DatabaseTarget(Name=WS_TRACE): Error when writing to database. Exception: System.Data.OracleClient.OracleException (0x80131938): ORA-01843: Invalid month

**the code is:**

```
 SetPropGDC(LogEntity);
 NLog.LogLevel logLevel = SetLogLevel(Level.Debug);
 logger.Log(logLevel, "try");
 ClearGDC();

 private void SetPropGDC(LogEntity LogEntity)
    {
        GlobalDiagnosticsContext.Set(processId, LogEntity.PROCESS_ID.ToString());
        GlobalDiagnosticsContext.Set("TIME_STAMP", DateTime.Now);
        GlobalDiagnosticsContext.Set(customerId, LogEntity.CUSTOMER_ID.ToString());

    }
```

```xml
  <targets>
    <target name="TRACEDatabase" type="DataBase"  keepConnection="false" 
             dbProvider="Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client" connectionString="${gdc:connectionString}"
             commandText="insert into TLOG_SITE_GENERAL_TRACE( PROCESS_ID,TIME_STAMP,CUSTOMER_ID)
                           values(:PROCESS_ID,:TIME_STAMP,:CUSTOMER_ID)">
      <parameter name="PROCESS_ID" layout="${gdc:PROCESS_ID}" />
      <parameter name="TIME_STAMP" layout="${gdc:TIME_STAMP}" dbType="OracleDbType.Date" />
      <parameter name="CUSTOMER_ID" layout="${gdc:CUSTOMER_ID}" />

    </target>
  </targets>
```

I tried in the Web.config to change the line:

```xml
<parameter name="TIME_STAMP" layout="${gdc:TIME_STAMP}" dbType="OracleDbType.Date" />
```

to:

```xml
<parameter name="TIME_STAMP" layout="${longDate}" dbType="OracleDbType.Date" />
```

and I got the same error

Comment: What's the NLog version? Are you using NuGet to load the NLog package?

Comment: Duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59018213/add-record-in-nlog-to-field-with-datatype-date

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution!
I changed the dbType parameter from:

```
 <parameter name="TIME_STAMP" layout="${gdc:TIME_STAMP}" dbType="OracleDbType.Date"  />
```

To:

```
 <parameter name="TIME_STAMP" layout="${gdc:TIME_STAMP}" dbType="DateTime" />
```

and it works!

Comment: I like to upvote this, but it's unclear if this is a fix or a try. Also does this work with ${longdate}? Then I advise you to do that.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, it's highly recommend to use the built in layout renderers.

For example, `${longdate}`, but also `${processid}`. Those are optimized and easier to use. 
You can find all of them [here](https://nlog-project.org/config/?tab=layout-renderers)

Be aware is that using global context (GDC), could be dangerous in multi threaded programs. Also in single threaded you could "leak" some context.

But I guess the **real issue** here is that your NLog is out to date. DbType support is added in NLog 4.6.

So first update NLog (using Nuget is highly recommend). I use here NLog 4.6.3+, but would recommend to update to NLog 4.7

Then for the code I would recommend to do this:

```
logger.WithProperty("CustomerId", LogEntity.CUSTOMER_ID).Log(loglevel, "Message");
```

and configure like this:

```xml
<targets>
    <target name="TRACEDatabase" type="DataBase"  keepConnection="false" 
             dbProvider="Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client" connectionString="${gdc:connectionString}"
             commandText="insert into TLOG_SITE_GENERAL_TRACE( PROCESS_ID,TIME_STAMP,CUSTOMER_ID)
                           values(:PROCESS_ID,:TIME_STAMP,:CUSTOMER_ID)">
      <parameter name="PROCESS_ID" layout="${processid}" dbType="Int32" />
      <parameter name="TIME_STAMP" layout="${longdate}" dbType="Date" />
      <parameter name="CUSTOMER_ID" layout="${event-properties:CUSTOMER_ID}"  dbType="Int32"  />
    </target>
</targets>
```

See also [${event-properties}](https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/EventProperties-Layout-Renderer)

There is no need for using a specific OracleDbType, so therefor I choose to just use "Date" (which is `DbType.Date`, see [DbType](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.dbtype)